# JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' -react native error

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error in an screen where I am fetching API but I checked the api fetch it is returning data in the JSON format. I am not able to get the point .

```
makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });


    fetch(url,{method:'GET'} )
             .then(res => res.json())
             .then(res => {
                 this.setState({
                     data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
                     error: res.error || null,
                     loading: false,
                     refreshing: false
                 });
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 this.setState({ error, loading: false });
             });


};
```

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think Unexpected token < means that your json data return an error value instead of the right one.

I think you have a typo in your link, isn't it should be like this?

```
`https://randomuser.me/api?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Can you check if that url returns the right json value?

Comment: Yes that is returning right JSON value . The problem is not data , as soon as I get the data on screen this error comes and data is also available on the screen .

Comment: If that is the case, I recommend to do a step by step debugging. First, comment out all your fetch function and try to console log your url value, make sure it is correct. If it is all good, then try to manually console log value that you get from your fetch after the "then" callback